# JPA specific solution for soft delete of entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate JPA implementation in our code. I want to perform soft delete of entity using JPA. I know for soft delete, hibernate provides `@SQLDelete` annotations. But I am looking for JPA specific solution. Is there any JPA specific solution for soft delete of entity?

Comment: Hope this will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323557/handling-soft-deletes-with-spring-jpa

Comment: This link, talks about hibernate specific solution. I am looking for JPA one.