# Spring Data: default 'not deleted' logic for automatic method-based queries when using soft-delete policy

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Let's say we use soft-delete policy: nothing gets deleted from the storage; instead, a 'deleted' attribute/column is set to true on a record/document/whatever to make it 'deleted'. Later, only non-deleted entries should be returned by query methods.

Let's take MongoDB as an example (alghough JPA is also interesting).

For standard methods defined by `MongoRepository`, we can extend the default implementation (`SimpleMongoRepository`), override the methods of interest and make them ignore 'deleted' documents.

But, of course, we'd also like to use custom query methods like

```
List<Person> findByFirstName(String firstName)
```

In a soft-delete environment, we are forced to do something iike

```
List<person> findByFirstNameAndDeletedIsFalse(String firstName)
```

or write queries manually with `@Query` (adding the same boilerplate condition about 'not deleted' all the time).

**Here comes the question**: is it possible to add this 'non-deleted' condition to any generated query automatically? I did not find anything in the documentation.

I'm looking at Spring Data (Mongo and JPA) 2.1.6.

#### Similar questions

1. [Query interceptor for spring-data-mongodb for soft deletions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807143/query-interceptor-for-spring-data-mongodb-for-soft-deletions) here they suggest Hibernate's `@Where` annotation which only works for JPA+Hibernate, and it is not clear how to override it if you still need to access deleted items in some queries
2. [Handling soft-deletes with Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323557/handling-soft-deletes-with-spring-jpa) here people either suggest the same `@Where`-based approach, or the solution applicability is limited with the already-defined standard methods, not the custom ones.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that for Mongo (at least, for spring-data-mongo 2.1.6) we can hack into standard `QueryLookupStrategy` implementation to add the desired 'soft-deleted documents are not visible by finders' behavior:

```
public class SoftDeleteMongoQueryLookupStrategy implements QueryLookupStrategy {
    private final QueryLookupStrategy strategy;
    private final MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public SoftDeleteMongoQueryLookupStrategy(QueryLookupStrategy strategy,
            MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
    }

    @Override
    public RepositoryQuery resolveQuery(Method method, RepositoryMetadata metadata, ProjectionFactory factory,
            NamedQueries namedQueries) {
        RepositoryQuery repositoryQuery = strategy.resolveQuery(method, metadata, factory, namedQueries);

        // revert to the standard behavior if requested
        if (method.getAnnotation(SeesSoftlyDeletedRecords.class) != null) {
            return repositoryQuery;
        }

        if (!(repositoryQuery instanceof PartTreeMongoQuery)) {
            return repositoryQuery;
        }
        PartTreeMongoQuery partTreeQuery = (PartTreeMongoQuery) repositoryQuery;

        return new SoftDeletePartTreeMongoQuery(partTreeQuery);
    }

    private Criteria notDeleted() {
        return new Criteria().orOperator(
                where("deleted").exists(false),
                where("deleted").is(false)
        );
    }

    private class SoftDeletePartTreeMongoQuery extends PartTreeMongoQuery {
        SoftDeletePartTreeMongoQuery(PartTreeMongoQuery partTreeQuery) {
            super(partTreeQuery.getQueryMethod(), mongoOperations);
        }

        @Override
        protected Query createQuery(ConvertingParameterAccessor accessor) {
            Query query = super.createQuery(accessor);
            return withNotDeleted(query);
        }

        @Override
        protected Query createCountQuery(ConvertingParameterAccessor accessor) {
            Query query = super.createCountQuery(accessor);
            return withNotDeleted(query);
        }

        private Query withNotDeleted(Query query) {
            return query.addCriteria(notDeleted());
        }
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface SeesSoftlyDeletedRecords {
}
```

We just add 'and not deleted' condition to all the queries unless `@SeesSoftlyDeletedRecords` asks as to avoid it.

Then, we need the following infrastructure to plug our `QueryLiikupStrategy` implementation:

```
public class SoftDeleteMongoRepositoryFactory extends MongoRepositoryFactory {
    private final MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public SoftDeleteMongoRepositoryFactory(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(mongoOperations);
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
    }

    @Override
    protected Optional<QueryLookupStrategy> getQueryLookupStrategy(QueryLookupStrategy.Key key,
            QueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider evaluationContextProvider) {
        Optional<QueryLookupStrategy> optStrategy = super.getQueryLookupStrategy(key,
                evaluationContextProvider);
        return optStrategy.map(this::createSoftDeleteQueryLookupStrategy);
    }

    private SoftDeleteMongoQueryLookupStrategy createSoftDeleteQueryLookupStrategy(QueryLookupStrategy strategy) {
        return new SoftDeleteMongoQueryLookupStrategy(strategy, mongoOperations);
    }
}

public class SoftDeleteMongoRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends Repository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable>
        extends MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

    public SoftDeleteMongoRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport getFactoryInstance(MongoOperations operations) {
        return new SoftDeleteMongoRepositoryFactory(operations);
    }
}
```

Then we just need to reference the factory bean in a `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation like this:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = SoftDeleteMongoRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

If it is required to determine dynamically whether a particular repository needs to be 'soft-delete' or a regular 'hard-delete' repository, we can introspect the repository interface (or the domain class) and decide whether we need to change the `QueryLookupStrategy` or not.

As for JPA, this approach does not work without rewriting (possibly duplicating) a substantial part of the code in `PartTreeJpaQuery`.