# Rest api spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jira-rest-api

i am working in rest api via spring.

i have `isdeleted` a field in a table i need to find if `isdeleted =0` in mysql then it show the data in row in a table as well as in application list but if `isdeleted=1`,the data remains in table in database but doesn't show in list in applicatiopn that is soft delete,how could i implement this condition in repository file by using `findall()` method

```
public interface FoodCourtRepository  extends JpaRepository<FoodCourtEntity, Long> {


    List<FoodCourtEntity> findAll(isdeleted=false???);


}
```

Comment: Create a custom RowMapper , Take reference from this [RowMapper](https://www.javatpoint.com/RowMapper-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling soft-deletes with Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323557/handling-soft-deletes-with-spring-jpa)

Comment: Dear thanks for response it not getting right  this codition is having one solution  by  in repository file ((select e from foodstallentity where e.isdelete=0" ))but i have to find this by another condition

Comment: <S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> example);                public interface FoodCourtRepository  extends JpaRepository<FoodCourtEntity, Long> {
 
 
 List<FoodCourtEntity> findAll(isdeleted=false);
 

} how could i apply this condition by this method(( <S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> example);)) in spring suite tool in repository file

Comment: That boolean flag seems like a bad, non-RESTful design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following method to your interface repository:

```
List<FoodCourtEntity> findByDeleted(boolean isDeleted);
```

You can learn more from
[Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)