# Spring Data Repo General Criteria

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring Data repository with multiple find methods like below.

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends 
CrudRepository<UserView>, Integer> {

@Override
Optional<Users> findById(Integer aLong);
List<Users> findAllAccountNotNull...
List<Users> findAllThat....
List<Users> findAllThisToo....
....

}
```

Now according to a new requirement, I want to add a criteria to **ALL** of this methods for example,

```
List<Users> findAll...NotInUserBlocked
```

So **all** above find statements should work with a common criteria of "find all users only who are not blocked". I can add this one by one to all find methods and also update all the methods that are calling these. But there are many. Is there a better way of doing this from a central place? And more cleanly?

Edit: Please note that this is a view. And the soft delete I want to make is on a different entity(Account). So A field in User view is constructed by taking into account User.Account.isNotBlocked.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323557/handling-soft-deletes-with-spring-jpa

Comment: You can try to use AOP to intercept the method that compiles criteria into a query based on given predicate list, and add extra predicate (`user is not blocked`) to that list