# Spring-Hibernate how soft delete/Filter with complex query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use Spring Data JPA and Hibernate trying to implement soft delete. All examples I seen are very simple where clauses like a boolean check. What I need is for example soft delete all dogs if their breed is in a list of banned breeds for example. I have a dynamic list:

```
List<String> bannedBreedsComesFromPropertiesFile = Arrays.asList("beagle", "terrier", "dalmation")
```

And repo:

```
public interface DogRepository extends CrudRepository<Dog, Integer> {

   findAllBy....
   findAllBy...
   findAllBy... 
   ....
}
```

So the breed filter should apply to all above findAll methods.

And then I want to achieve a soft delete/Filter with these dog breeds from DB:

```
  @Entity
  @Where(clause="breed != Not in list bannedBreedsComesFromPropertiesFile")

  public class Dog{


  @Column(name="breed")
  private String breed;

 }
```

How can I achieve this? I cant find the correct syntax if it exists.

Comment: Soft delete would relate to setting some flag to indicate a record is deleted rather than physically deleting it. From the code you have posted it looks like you only want to filter the records by some criteria. These are 2 completely different things.Additionally, surely banned breeds should be in the database rather than in a properties file.

Comment: @Alan Hay thanks . you are right do, you have a solution for filters? I see there is FilterDef annotation but cant see how I can send a dynamic list to that. To your second remark, banned breeds needs to be updated frequently, and for the moment properties file its good enough

Comment: @AlanHay Also you can see more details on my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061546/spring-data-repo-general-criteria