# Who should be parent in spring JPA relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 tables `book`, `publisher`, `author`. Here `author` and `publisher` can refer to same record in `book` therefore I decided to make `book` as relationship parent.

However I also want to make it so that if a `publisherA` is deleted, all the `book` record related to `publisherA` also get deleted. same goes for `author`.

I tried using cascade, but it ended up doing the opposite, if I delete a `book`, it would delete any `publisher` and `author` related to the book.

Here are my Tables

```
create table publisher(
    `PUBLISHER_ID` int auto_increment,
    `PUBLISHER_NAME` varchar(150),
    `CONTACT_NO` varchar(10),
    `EMAIL` varchar(30),
    `ADDRESS_LINE_1` varchar(255),
    `ADDRESS_LINE_2` varchar(255),
    `CITY` varchar(50),
    `STATE` varchar(50),
    `PINCODE` varchar(6),
    primary key(PUBLISHER_ID)
    );
    
create table author_book(
    `AUTHOR_ID` INT,
    `BOOK_ID` INT
);

create table author(
    `AUTHOR_ID` int auto_increment,
    `FIRST_NAME` varchar(255),
    `LAST_NAME` varchar(255),
    `EMAIL` varchar(30),
    `CONTACT_NO` VARCHAR(10),
    primary key(AUTHOR_ID)
);
create table book(
    `BOOK_ID` int auto_increment,
    `TITLE` varchar(255),
    `SUBJECT` varchar(255),
    `PUBLISHED_YEAR` int,
    `ISBN` varchar(30),
    `QUANTITY` int,
    `SHELF_DETAILS` varchar(255),    
    `PUBLISHER_ID` int,
    `BOOK_COST` INT,
    primary key(BOOK_ID)
);
```

`author` Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="author")
public class Authors {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="AUTHOR_ID")
    private int authorId;
    
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="CONTACT_NO")
    private String contactNo;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Books> books = new HashSet<Books>();

    //getter setter
}
```

`publisher` Entity

```
package com.sprint.proj.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "publisher")
public class Publishers {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="PUBLISHER_ID")
    private int publisherId;
    
    @Column(name="PUBLISHER_NAME")
    private String publisherName;
    
    @Column(name="CONTACT_NO")
    private String contactNo;
    
    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="ADDRESS_LINE_1")
    private String address1;
    
    @Column(name="ADDRESS_LINE_2")
    private String address2;
    
    @Column(name="CITY")
    private String city;
    
    @Column(name="STATE")
    private String state;
    
    @Column(name="PINCODE")
    private int pincode;
// getter and setters
}
```

`book` Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Books implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="BOOK_ID")
    private int bookId;
    
    @Column(name="TITLE")
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name="SUBJECT")
    private String subject;
    
    @Column(name="PUBLISHED_YEAR")
    private int publishedYear;
    
    @Column(name="ISBN")
    private String isbn;
    
    @Column(name="QUANTITY")
    private int quantity;
    
    @Column(name="SHELF_DETAILS")
    private String shelfDetails;
    
    @Column(name="BOOK_COST")
    private int bookCost;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "author_book", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID") })
    private Set<Authors> authors = new HashSet<Authors>();
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PUBLISHER_ID")
    private Publishers publisher;
// getter and setters
}
```

Comment: I would leave mapping as is and do deletion manually.

Comment: What should happen if a book has multiple authors and you delete only one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done at MySQL level via proper foreign key constraints, for example for the `book`/`publisher` relationship:

```sql
alter table book
add constraint fk_book_publisher_id
  foreign key (PUBLISHER_ID)
  references publisher(PUBLISHER_ID)
  -- no action on update,
  -- unless you want to allow publisher's PK (PUBLISHER_ID) to be updated
  -- (but I guess not):
  on update no action
  -- when the referenced record is deleted
  -- (so the record from table publisher),
  -- delete the referencing records too
  -- (so the records from table book):
  on delete cascade;
```

Concerning the `book`/`author` relationship though, your model seems to allow one book to have mutliple authors (and one author multiple books), hence the `author_book` join table in the middle. In this case, FKs won't allow cascading deletes from `author` to `book` unfortunately (they would leave books "author-less"). This will need to be done by the app (perhaps doable by JPA). Although, what should happen if a book has multiple authors and you delete only one of them?

Answer (score 1):

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "authors" , cascade = Cascade.ALL)
private Set<Books> books = new HashSet<Books>();

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) --> ignore cascade here so it will be none
@JoinTable(name = "author_book", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID") })
private Set<Authors> authors = new HashSet<Authors>();
```

Actually you can use author repository to delete Book with cascade all but if you delete with book repository you won't delete author because it is ignored in @ManyToMany relation. In two cases relation table's record is always deleted.

Also you don't need to specify on update or on delete actions in database script.

Answer (score 0):

I would like recommend to soft delete manually via update.

https://blog.staynoob.cn/post/2019/05/when-soft-delete-meets-unique-index/

Then add where clause to  entity to get only not deleted entities from repository

[Handling soft-deletes with Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323557/handling-soft-deletes-with-spring-jpa)