# Hibernate - apply @Where when fetching

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using following annotation on my Hibernate entity class

```
@Table(name="cms_user", schema="public")
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
public class User {
  ..
}
```

So it does not load records that are "soft deleted". But when I fetch this entity as part of another query:

```
queryRoot.fetch("cmsUser", JoinType.INNER);
```

this where clause is not applied and also deleted users are visible. Of course I can filter them out then, but I am looking for an efficient way to set this `deleted = false` on single place and @Where or some other hibernate class annotation is a great candiadate.

Is there any way how can I annotate my hibernate class so `deleted = false` is applied also for fetches and joins?

Comment: Does this answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323557/handling-soft-deletes-with-spring-jpa

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej no, I already use `@Where` but I need to remove it from fetches as well and this is not described there.

Comment: Maybe this can help ? 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/WhereJoinTable.html

Comment: Maybe something like this also ... https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-exclude-deactivated-elements-from-association/

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich thanks, these links are helpful. I used `@Where` annotation on mapping which also galaxy mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't test it but try to add `@Where` annotation to your joined entity instead, in other words to your `@OneToMany` annotation.

```
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "joinedEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<User> userList;
```

Comment: thanks, this works the way I wanted to.

Comment: @michal.jakubeczy you're welcome